# Value from LaTeX package to plain TeX

Tags: latex-base

If I say `\usepackage{lastpage}` I got `\xdef\lastpage@lastpage{53}` at the end of `.aux`-file. I tested and

```
\xdef\sometest@sometest{53}

\newcount\tmp
\advance\tmp \sometest@sometest \relax
\advance\tmp -1 \relax
This document has \the\tmp {} pages (not counting titlepage).
```

works. However

```
\advance\tmp \lastpage@lastpage \relax
```

Does not. So how can I get values defined in some LaTeX package "to plain TeX", i.e. to be used with plain TeX commands like `\advance`?

Comment: I haven't spent any time really thinking about this, but: have you tried `\input{myfile.aux}` (or whatever the `.aux` file you want that macro from is called).  LaTeX includes it, but TeX does not, because the `.aux` file is a LaTeX innovation.

Comment: I am using LaTeX. I corrected my question by adding few words at the end.

Comment: Well, you'll never use any macro with an `@` in it unless you write `\makeatletter` first.  Perhaps that's your problem?  Also: if you're using LaTeX, you shouldn't be using `\newcount`, `\advance`, or `\xdef` at all, but rather the higher-level macros it provides (unless you intend to do "low-level programming").

Comment: Ryan, that was it. Please make it as answer (not as comment), so I can accept it and you got credits.

Comment: Also the aux file is read at the begin{document} time (I think) so your commands that actually use stuff need to do so afterwards.